# Como faço para sortear nomes aleatórios de cada lista sem repeti-los

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Eu quero sortear nomes aleatórios de 3 listas diferentes, tenho um programa em Python que faz mais ou menos isso. O problema é que eles fica repetindo vários nomes em combinações diferentes, gostaria que o programa pegasse apenas um nome de cada lista e formasse uma equipe.

```
from random import choice
from time import sleep

lista = []

j1 = ['Jose', 'Bruno', 'Lucas', 'Eduardo', 'Pedro', 'Luciano', 'Vitor', 'Diego', 'Rômulo', '*Pisca']
j2 = ['Carlinhos', 'Carlos', 'Davi', 'Thiago', 'Paulo', 'Igor', 'Felipe', 'Marcelo', 'Matheus', 'Fabio']
j3 = ['Artur', 'Anderson', 'Gustavo', 'Rogerio', 'Marcus', 'Nando', 'Jorge', 'Rodrigo', 'Caio', 'Jonas']

for c in range(1, 11):
    print('PROCESSANDO.....')
    sleep(2)
    print('-' * 20)
    print(f'      \033[34mEQUIPE {c}\033[m')
    print('-' * 20)
    sorteio = (f'{choice(j1)}\n'
               f'{choice(j2)}\n'
               f'{choice(j3)}')
    print(sorteio)
    print('-' * 20)
```

Answer (score 7):

Você pode simplesmente embaralhar as listas e em seguida percorrê-las com [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (que serve para percorrer várias listas ao mesmo tempo):

```
from random import shuffle

j1 = ['Jose', 'Bruno', 'Lucas', 'Eduardo', 'Pedro', 'Luciano', 'Vitor', 'Diego', 'Rômulo', '*Pisca']
j2 = ['Carlinhos', 'Carlos', 'Davi', 'Thiago', 'Paulo', 'Igor', 'Felipe', 'Marcelo', 'Matheus', 'Fabio']
j3 = ['Artur', 'Anderson', 'Gustavo', 'Rogerio', 'Marcus', 'Nando', 'Jorge', 'Rodrigo', 'Caio', 'Jonas']

shuffle(j1)
shuffle(j2)
shuffle(j3)

for n, (c1, c2, c3) in enumerate(zip(j1, j2, j3), start=1):
    # imprime as outras mensagens, etc
    print(f'      \033[34mEQUIPE {n}\033[m')
    print(f'{c1}\n{c2}\n{c3}')
```

Eu também uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para obter o índice ao mesmo tempo em que percorro as listas (e uso o argumento `start` para que a contagem comece com 1, já que por padrão ela começa em zero). Isso é melhor do que usar um `range` específico, pois assim funciona independente do tamanho das listas (assumindo que todas elas têm o mesmo tamanho, já que `zip` se encerra quando a menor delas terminar).

Assim, a cada iteração, `n` é o índice e `c1`, `c2` e `c3` são um dos nomes das listas `j1`, `j2` e `j3`. E como elas foram embaralhadas anteriormente, eu garanto que as equipes serão escolhidas aleatoriamente.

---

O problema é que [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) acaba modificando a própria lista.

Se quiser manter as listas originais intactas, você pode usar [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), que retorna outra lista embaralhada:

```
from random import sample

j1 = ['Jose', 'Bruno', 'Lucas', 'Eduardo', 'Pedro', 'Luciano', 'Vitor', 'Diego', 'Rômulo', '*Pisca']
j2 = ['Carlinhos', 'Carlos', 'Davi', 'Thiago', 'Paulo', 'Igor', 'Felipe', 'Marcelo', 'Matheus', 'Fabio']
j3 = ['Artur', 'Anderson', 'Gustavo', 'Rogerio', 'Marcus', 'Nando', 'Jorge', 'Rodrigo', 'Caio', 'Jonas']

def embaralha(lista): # retorna uma cópia da lista, só que embaralhada
    return sample(lista, k=len(lista))

for n, (c1, c2, c3) in enumerate(zip(embaralha(j1), embaralha(j2), embaralha(j3)), start=1):
    print(f'      \033[34mEQUIPE {n}\033[m')
    print(f'{c1}\n{c2}\n{c3}')
```

Ou ainda:

```
for n, (c1, c2, c3) in enumerate(zip(*map(embaralha, [j1, j2, j3])), start=1):
    print(f'      \033[34mEQUIPE {n}\033[m')
    print(f'{c1}\n{c2}\n{c3}')
```

Comment: Aff, ia responder isso bem agora :( [repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BigJudiciousGlitch#main.py) já estava pronto...

Comment: @Woss Eu tava vendo se o `itertools` tem alguma coisa pronta, mas não achei (mas talvez dê pra fazer alguma "mágica", sei lá).. Fica aí a sugestão pra outra possível resposta :-)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode remover o item sorteado da lista. Veja abaixo:

```
from random import choice
from time import sleep

lista = []

j1 = ['Jose', 'Bruno', 'Lucas', 'Eduardo', 'Pedro', 'Luciano', 'Vitor', 'Diego', 'Rômulo', '*Pisca']
j2 = ['Carlinhos', 'Carlos', 'Davi', 'Thiago', 'Paulo', 'Igor', 'Felipe', 'Marcelo', 'Matheus', 'Fabio']
j3 = ['Artur', 'Anderson', 'Gustavo', 'Rogerio', 'Marcus', 'Nando', 'Jorge', 'Rodrigo', 'Caio', 'Jonas']

for c in range(1, 11):
    print('PROCESSANDO.....')
    sleep(2)
    print('-' * 20)
    print(f'      \033[34mEQUIPE {c}\033[m')
    print('-' * 20)
    #
    j1_player = choice(j1)
    j1.remove(j1_player)
    j2_player = choice(j2)
    j2.remove(j2_player)
    j3_player = choice(j3)
    j3.remove(j3_player)
    #
    sorteio = (f'{j1_player}\n'
               f'{j2_player}\n'
               f'{j3_player}')
    print(sorteio)
    print('-' * 20)
```

Exemplo de saída

```
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 1
--------------------
*Pisca
Paulo
Caio
--------------------
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 2
--------------------
Pedro
Igor
Jorge
--------------------
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 3
--------------------
Diego
Carlos
Artur
--------------------
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 4
--------------------
Vitor
Felipe
Jonas
--------------------
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 5
--------------------
Luciano
Fabio
Anderson
--------------------
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 6
--------------------
Rômulo
Carlinhos
Nando
--------------------
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 7
--------------------
Lucas
Thiago
Rodrigo
--------------------
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 8
--------------------
Jose
Marcelo
Gustavo
--------------------
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 9
--------------------
Bruno
Davi
Rogerio
--------------------
PROCESSANDO.....
--------------------
      EQUIPE 10
--------------------
Eduardo
Matheus
Marcus
--------------------
```

**UPDATE**

Caso todos os nomes possam estar em uma lista única, tem outra forma (mais simples) de fazer que a primeira, veja abaixo:

```
>>> j = ['Jose', 'Bruno', 'Lucas', 'Eduardo', 'Pedro', 'Luciano', 'Vitor', 'Diego', 'Rômulo', '*Pisca', 'Carlinhos', 'Carlos', 'Davi', 'Thiago', 'Paulo', 'Igor', 'Felipe', 'Marcelo', 'Matheus', 'Fabio', 'Artur', 'Anderson', 'Gustavo', 'Rogerio', 'Marcus', 'Nando', 'Jorge', 'Rodrigo', 'Caio', 'Jonas']
>>>
>>> while len(j) != 0:
...     random.shuffle(j)
...     print(j[:3])
...     j = j[3:]
...
['Rômulo', 'Rodrigo', '*Pisca']
['Luciano', 'Nando', 'Carlos']
['Jonas', 'Eduardo', 'Igor']
['Fabio', 'Davi', 'Lucas']
['Thiago', 'Marcus', 'Paulo']
['Vitor', 'Felipe', 'Bruno']
['Anderson', 'Pedro', 'Marcelo']
['Caio', 'Artur', 'Matheus']
['Rogerio', 'Diego', 'Carlinhos']
['Jose', 'Jorge', 'Gustavo']
>>>
```

Espero que ajude